# How to run two processes with dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, server, dockerfile, command

I need to run uvicorn server process and my python script (which is another process).
Since uvicorn start a process that doesn't end, the second command will not start. So i ask you if you know some workaround to overcome this problem.

I tried to do this command:

```
CMD cd Manager ; uvicorn ManagerBot:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 && python ManagerBot.py
```

also this:

```
CMD cd Manager ; uvicorn ManagerBot:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 ; python ManagerBot.py
```

But the script doesn't start (only the uvicorn server start)
I remind you that, the script, is another process that doesn't end so the "viceversa" will not work.

Comment: write an entry point script that is invoked when the container starts, the will be PID 1, then use your entry point script to launch the other processes in the background

Comment: Despite the answers given, please try avoiding this approach in production. Think twice about how you can achieve the same using either a single process or putting another process in a second container, then connect them using some network protocol.

Comment: I'll echo @igobr's point: the right way to do this is to run two separate containers, with one foreground process in each.  You can easily override the `CMD` when you run the container, and run the two containers with different commands but from the same image.

Comment: I need this workaround in order to deploy a telegram bot.

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper script, e.g. `run.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Start the first process
cd Manager
uvicorn ManagerBot:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 &
  
# Start the second process
python ManagerBot.py &
  
# Wait for any process to exit
wait -n
  
# Exit with status of process that exited first
exit $?
```

Then, in Dockerfile:

```
... 
COPY run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

Comment: It doesn't work due uvicorn. 
I have a directory "Manager", inside it, i have ManagerBot.py and the dockerfile

Comment: @AndreaBasile you are free to add `cd Manager` where you need it. I have updated my answer, check it out.